# Make database connection persistant

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I have a `superset` container running with a `postgreSQL`database.All is working fine. I can see my table and making queries from superset SQL Lab.

- I also added `dataset`, created `chart` and `dashboard`.

However when I stop my containers and restart them, I lost all `datasets`, `charts` and `dashboard`. I even lost the `database connection` I made before (URI method)

Is something wrong with my docker-compose file? How can I avoid this?

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  superset:
    build:
      context: ./superset
      dockerfile: dockerfile
      extra_hosts:
        - "edge.tdp:141.94.172.122"
    container_name: superset
    environment:
      - ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@superset.com
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - '8088:8088'
    volumes:
      - .:/app/tdp
    
  db:
    container_name: postgresql
    image: postgres:15
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass your database info to the Superset container to use your Postgres instance as backend database.

This should get you going:

```yaml
  superset:
    environment:
      - ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@superset.com
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - DATABASE_DB=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_DIALECT=postgresql
```

This is the relevant config file that reads those environment variables: [`superset_conig.py`](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py)

Ultimately, depends on the custom Dockerfile you use which you didn't provide.

**Edit**: See how Apache Superset build their [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker-compose-non-dev.yml)